# Are there laws for the Foldable typeclass that constrain how Foldable instances can be derived?

Tags: haskell, deriving, foldable

I'm experimenting with the `Foldable` typeclass in Haskell, using the following data type as an example:

```
data Tree a = Empty
            | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

If I use the `DeriveFoldable` GHC extension, it seems to derive a `Foldable` instance along the lines of

```
instance Foldable Tree where
  foldMap _ Empty = mempty
  foldMap f (Node l n r) = (foldMap f l) <> (f n) <> (foldMap f r)
```

i.e., an inorder traversal of the tree. However, I don't see anything obvious preventing a different `Foldable` instance, such as a preorder traversal:

```
instance Foldable Tree where
  foldMap _ Empty = mempty
  foldMap f (Node l n r) = (f n) <> (foldMap f l) <> (foldMap f r)
```

Are there laws for the `Foldable` typeclass that would make the preorder traversal instance unlawful?

Comment: The reason it derives it that way is because it uses the order of the parameters, if you defined it as `Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)`, it would be preorder traversal.

Comment: For a functor instance, it should satisfy `foldMap f = fold . fmap f` (as is specified in the documentation).

Comment: I do not see a problem with defining it with pre-order traversal. Although I would find it more sensical to do this with `Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)`, since then the datastructure "hints" how the foldable will look like.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So in short, there aren't any laws constraining how to create the instance, and `DeriveFoldable` just uses the parameter order? Sounds like a good answer.

Comment: well it should satisfy some laws, like `sum = getSum . foldMap Sum`, etc. to sum up the type. In essence the idea is that you fold over it satisfying monadic laws.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Foldable` has no laws guiding the order of traversal. In fact, we can think of the act of writing a `Foldable` instance as choosing a specific order of traversal. If `DeriveFoldable` is used, the choice will be to follow the order of the fields in the definition of the type (see also [Daniel Wagner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61916908/2751851)); the details are documented in [the relevant section of the GHC User's Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#deriving-foldable-instances).

(Side note: As discussed in [dfeuer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61918238/2751851), `Traversable` has richer laws that, among other things, limit the range of acceptable `foldMap` implementations. Still, both inorder and preorder traversals for your `Tree` give out lawful implementations of `Traversable`.)

Answer (score 6):

`Foldable` itself is very poor in laws. The fundamental method is `foldMap`. Other methods are expected to behave like their default definitions up to laziness details. Two laws arise from parametricity:

1. If `g :: m -> n` is a monoid morphism and `f :: a -> m` is a function, then

   ```
   g . foldMap f = foldMap (g . f)
   ```
2. If the `Foldable` is also a `Functor`, then for all functions `g :: b -> m` and `f :: a -> b`,

   ```
   foldMap (g . f) = foldMap g . fmap f
   ```

In practice, most `Foldable` instances are also `Traversable`. `Traversable` has much richer laws for `traverse`, and imposes the law that

```
foldMap f = getConst . traverse (Const . f)
```

This guarantees that for a `Traversable`, every element in the container is folded over exactly once. Whereas

```
instance Foldable [] where
  foldMap _ [] = mempty
  foldMap f (x:_:xs) = f x <> f x <> foldMap f xs
```

would be perfectly valid, there's no lawful `Traversable` instance that matches.

Answer (score 5):

No, there are no laws that tell what order fields must be visited in. It is conventional to visit fields in the order they appear in the data structure definition (or at least the user-visible API, if pattern synonyms are used), but this is convention only.